# Dynamic key in data passed to template

Tags: mustache

How do I access a dynamic key in the template?

If the data coming from the server is of the following format:

`hash = {
 'User001' : {
             'LastLoggedIn' : '42301',
             'Name' : 'John'
  },
  'user' : 'User001'
}`

If I want to use the User001.Name in my template, how do I do it? I will know it is 'User001' or 'User002' only from the 'user' attribute!

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you should prepare your data before passing it to Mustache. A good way to do this is to wrap it in a View or ViewModel object, rather than simply passing in a JSON hash.